# Creating a UNIQUE constraint from a JSON object

Tags: postgresql, json, unique-constraint

Lets take some example table peoples , that got only 2 fields: id and data(json).

```
SELECT data FROM peoples ;
{"name": "Adam","pos":"DBA","age":22 }
{"name": "Alice","pos":"Security","age":33 }
{"name": "Bob","pos":"Manager","age":42 }
```

I want to create constraint for "pos" field, that must be unique. 
I've searched over the internet about JSON constraints but no results.

How can I handle this problem ?

Comment: JSON is used for schema-less, unstructured data. If you want constraints, you should properly normalize your data.

Comment: _'Normalize, normalize, normalize!'_ (V. I. dezso)

Comment: Nosql dbs such as Mongo support this. Why not do it in sql server? I think it's useful

Answer (score 39, accepted):

First and foremost: I agree with both the comments of @a_horse_with_no_name and @dezso: **you should normalize your data**. JSON is *not* for that.

However, if some  reason I cannot fathom really makes this an advantage, it is possible:

Create an [expression based `UNIQUE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX people_data_pos_idx ON peoples( (data->>'pos') ) ;
```

If, at this point, you try to insert the following piece of data into your table (with an already existing ->>pos):

```
INSERT INTO peoples(data)
VALUES
    ('{"name": "Eve", "pos":"DBA", "age":34}') ;
```

You get this as a response:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "people_data_pos_idx"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key ((data ->> 'pos'::text))=(DBA) already exists.
```

NOTE: I've assumed that `data.pos` will always be a string. If you want to generalize, you can use `( (data->'pos') )` instead. You would index then a JSON(B) expression instead of a text. Check [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: That might result in a sparse table.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @baash05? What is "sparse table" in this context, and what issue does this imply? I'm considering this same solution suggested by @joanolo but I'd like to also weigh the downsides properly

Comment: @tmilar Did you find an answer to that question?